# Разработка игр для планшетов на JavaScript

Tags: android, javascript, objective-c, php, perl

Javascript я знаю уже очень много лет. Это мой самый любимый язык. Использую его ежедневно для написания сайтов. JQuery использую только на работе. Я слышал, что на javascript можно писать игры. 6 лет назад в эпоху IE6 я написал игру на подобии Диабло на яваскрипте. Принцип был простой, при щелчке мышью я управлял скрол барами, а герой находился в центре экрана постоянно, только меняя направление, так же кстати и в диабло 2 сделано. Сейчас я с легкостью мог бы написать такую игру, тогда, например,  позиционирование приходилось использовать по таймеру, потому что фиксед не работал, но все это в прошлом.

Как думаете, каким образом можно продавать такие игры и где они будут работать?

Какими инструментами разработки пользуются разработчики, и вообще можно ли делать игры на javascript?

Есть ли смысл заниматься разработкой игр на javascript?

А если вы разрабатываете или разрабатывали, то поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Имхо, игры на джаваСкрипте - это из серии для мазохистов.

Comment: http://phonegap.com/developer

Comment: @dgfhgjljhjjd, не забывайте принимать верные ответы!

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Думаю при текущем состоянии рынка казуальную игру можно хорошо продать в двух местах.

- В Facebook, Vkontakte.
- На Android market и Appstore.

С первым вариантом я не знаком, со вторым C/С++ в помощь. При этом в начале игра пишется под Windows в Visual Studio и только потом портируется под Android и в случае хороших продаж там делается порт на iOS. Это реально удобнее чем копаться с эмулятором и реальными устройствами. Я работаю по такой схеме. При этом, чтобы избежать проблем с портированием код самого движка пишется в С стиле без использования STL, boost, ООП, шаблонов, лишних WinAPI вызовов. Также используется минимальное количество внешних C библиотек от надежных поставщиков информация об успешной сборке которых под нужные платформы уже существует в интернете.

P.S. Писать на javascript это реально плохая идея на 99% обреченная на провал.

Comment: Ничего личного, просто минус

Comment: @AlexWindHope, написал то же самое))

Answer (score 3):

Сам не пишу но знаю что в Unity 3d пишут на JavaScript или С#. Учитывая насколько мощный инструмент и востребованность его сейчас (как минимум для iOS) думаю Вы можете перспективно работать.

Comment: не могу не согласится, но как по мне жабоскрыпт для написания игр сильно медленный, в телефоне будет фпс сильно низкий, говорю из опыта написания игр на фонгепе \ кордове

Comment: Безусловно, недостатки есть, но тем не менее возможность разрабатывать на JS существует. Чем и интересовался топикстартер

Comment: А еще если постаратся можно сделать игру на CSS )))

Comment: @dajver - чаще всего это проблемы реализации API, поддержки браузеров, кривой сборки и т.д. и т.п., т.е. язык не причем, к тому-же практически все из них решаться с течением времени

Но, конечно, писать, масштабное mmoprg на JS'e не стоит, хотя и можно

Answer (score 1):

Ваш рассказ чем-то смахивает на историю Попова. По теме: сейчас пока у планшетов ресурсы не дотягивают, чтобы наиболее быстро исполнять код в браузере.

Answer (score 1):

Писать можно. А некоторые не только пишут, но и зарабатывают на них деньги. И это могут быть не только чистые веб-приложения, так как Win8 позволяет писать на JavaScript и декстопные приложения.
Касательно литературы, на английском - ее уже море. Главным образом, большинство игр строятся на базе нового API в HTML5 и элементе Canvas. На русском языке могу посоветовать этот материал - [HTML5 Games Development by Example/Разработка игр на HTML5](http://unmail22.narod.ru/Books/HTML5_Games/HTML5_Games.html)